# Group by DATEPART() error/mistake

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, datepart

I encountered a Group by DATEPART() clause Problem. My code is

```
SELECT con.Name, con.contractID, Sum(cplanit.Cost) as costs, DATENAME(month,month(cplanit.PaymentDate)) as month, year(cplanit.PaymentDate) as year

FROM ContractTable con

INNER JOIN [a lot of tables] ON [joins proofed and working fine]

Group By con.Name, con.contractID, DATEPART(month,cplanit.PaymentDate), DATEPART(year,cplanit.PaymentDate)
```

I'm getting this:

```
Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase  C00012121   18.7500 January 2011
Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase  C00012121   18.7500 January 2010
Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase  C00012121   18.7500 January 2011
Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase  C00012121   18.7500 January 2010
Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase  C00012121   18.7500 January 2011
```

Identical entries. Costs are grouped by the exact PaymentDate, rather than month and year - which is what I need to do. This problem stays if I remove Datename and year in the SELECT clause or if I group by month or year only. Grouping except for DATEPART(), month() or year() to group for works fine. Maybe it's something simple I missed? Sometimes I'm just blind.

Encountered in SQL Server Management Studio / SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Also: Why the group by clause is different to SELECT fields? Did you try : GROUP BY con.Name, con.contractID, DATENAME(month,month(cplanit.PaymentDate)), year(cplanit.PaymentDate)

Comment: "Costs are grouped by the exact PaymentDate" I have to correct myself here, there is only one PaymentDate per month, contrary to what I thought. Sorry for my post, I got the solution: The Joins produced just multiple lines. A 'distinct' solves it therefore. Thank you very much anyway, stackoverflow proofed very useful for me multiple times :)

Comment: @TedOckham . . . Consider deleting the question.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff "We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge.

Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?
" Well, this text scared me off from deleting it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not privide in GROUP BY clause fields which are provided in SELECT clause. Try following:

```
SELECT con.Name, con.contractID, Sum(cplanit.Cost) as costs, DATENAME(month,month(cplanit.PaymentDate)) as month, year(cplanit.PaymentDate) as year

FROM ContractTable con

INNER JOIN [a lot of tables] ON [joins proofed and working fine]

GROUP BY con.Name, con.contractID, DATENAME(month,month(cplanit.PaymentDate)), year(cplanit.PaymentDate)
```

---

Anyway It working in all cases:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tempas
(
   Name NVARCHAR(80),
   contractID NVARCHAR(20),
   Data DATETIME2
)
INSERT INTO #Tempas VALUES('Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase' ,'1','20010101 10:10:10')
INSERT INTO #Tempas VALUES('Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase' ,'1','20010101 10:10:10')
INSERT INTO #Tempas VALUES('Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase' ,'1','20010101 10:10:10')
INSERT INTO #Tempas VALUES('Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase' ,'1','20010101 10:10:10')
INSERT INTO #Tempas VALUES('Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase' ,'1','20020101 10:10:10')
INSERT INTO #Tempas VALUES('Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase' ,'1','20020101 10:10:10')
INSERT INTO #Tempas VALUES('Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase' ,'1','20020101 10:10:10')
INSERT INTO #Tempas VALUES('Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase' ,'1','20020101 10:10:10')

SELECT Name, contractID, DATENAME(month,month(data)) AS Month,  year(data) AS year 
FROM #Tempas 
GROUP BY Name, contractID,  DATEPART(month,data), DATEPART(year,data)

DROP TABLE #tempas
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
              Name                contractID Month  year
Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase  1   January 2001
Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase  1   January 2002
```

---

With the same values and following query:

```
SELECT Name, contractID, DATENAME(month,month(data)) AS Month,  year(data) AS year 
FROM #Tempas 
GROUP BY Name, contractID,  DATENAME(month,month(data)), year(data)
```

**OUTPUT same:**

```
              Name                contractID Month  year
Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase  1   January 2001
Adobe CLP Agreement - Initial purchase  1   January 2002
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work fine as it is, even with the current group by clause. Could the issue be in another part of your query ?

```
declare @ContractTable table (
Name nvarchar(20),
ContractId int,
Cost Decimal,
PaymentDate DateTime)

insert into @ContractTable values ('Name', 1, 100, N'20150101')
insert into @ContractTable values ('Name', 2, 100, N'20150101')
insert into @ContractTable values ('Name', 1, 100, N'20150102')
insert into @ContractTable values ('Name', 1, 100, N'20150102')
insert into @ContractTable values ('Name', 2, 100, N'20150104')
insert into @ContractTable values ('Name', 2, 100, N'20150104')
insert into @ContractTable values ('Name', 2, 100, N'20150105')
insert into @ContractTable values ('Name', 2, 100, N'20150105')
insert into @ContractTable values ('Name', 2, 100, N'20150105')
insert into @ContractTable values ('Name', 2, 100, N'20150105')

SELECT 
     Name
    ,contractID
    ,Sum(Cost) as costs
    ,DATENAME(month,month(PaymentDate)) as [month]
    ,year(PaymentDate) as [year]
FROM 
    @ContractTable
Group By 
     Name
    ,contractID
    ,DATEPART(month,PaymentDate)
    ,DATEPART(year, PaymentDate)
```